# How to launch an app when device is shaking using Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm planning to create an Android app where it's triggered when user shaking their device.

I found [this plugin](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-shake) and it seems like it's only working if user already inside the app.

How to make the device listen to the shake and open the app right away when user on the homescreen or locked screen?

Comment: to clarify, even in native development isn't possible to launch an app when device shake is detected, instead it's possible to detect device shake using accelerometer sensor inside a service which runs in background and than launch an activity from this service

Comment: what if an app causes a vibration you want your app to launch?

Comment: did you find any solution @zulhimil Zainudin